# Why is there no warning for uninitialized local variables in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I have a question: When the variable 'name' is global, I see a warning saying *'Property must be initialized or be abstract.'* However, if 'name' is local, I don't get any warning. I know Kotlin is designed to avoid null variables if not declared, but I'm confused why there's no warning for local variables. Can you help me understand this? If it's explained in the Kotlin documentation, please let me know where I can find it.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var name: String | String? //The warning that appears -> "Property must be initialized or be abstract"
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}

or

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var name: String | String? //There are no warnings
    }

}
```

Comment: What is "`String | String?`". That's not compiling for me.  And even if you could declare a variable of a having multiple types, `var name : String?` is sufficient to cover a nullable and non-nullable assignment.  But maybe I'm not using the same Kotlin version as you?

Comment: The compiler can relatively easily prove a local variable is not used before it is initialized, so you can "delay" initializing it. The same cannot be reliably proven for an instance property in all cases, so it forces you to initialize it during the object's construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local `name` inside `onCreate` is effectively getting optimized away since it's never referenced. (Or more precisely, the compiler can tell it's not used yet)  Update your code with something as trivial as:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var name: String?
        if (false) {
             println("$name")  // you definitely get a warning here
        }
    }
```

And you'll get a warning.